# How to cancel process and return failure response after given time for any request in spring boot rest webservices?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am using spring boot rest API and I want to kill any request that is taking more than 10 seconds to process and return a customized failure response to user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Hystrix (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works)
configure your timeout and fallback things.

You can configure Hystrix in your application with fewer changes.